# JPAControllers from entities not working for parent-child create

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink

I have a parent and child table.

```
schema: parent(int id,varchar desc), child(int id, varchar desc, int parent_id(foreignKey)).
```

From this I created entities and then JPAControllers from those entities using netbeans.
When I tried to store a parent with a collection of child it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.`. After inspecting the JPA controllers generated by netbeans, I found out that they are assuming that the child objects in the parent have an ID and in my case since the child objects are also new I don't have an ID for them. But what I don't understand is that why the following code is present in the netbeans generated JPAController code.

```
Collection<Child> attachedChildCollection = new ArrayList<Child>();
for (Child childCollectionChildToAttach : parent.getChildCollection()) {
    childCollectionChildToAttach = em.getReference(childCollectionChildToAttach.getClass(), childCollectionChildToAttach.getId());
    attachedChildCollection.add(childCollectionChildToAttach);
}
parent.setChildCollection(attachedChildCollection);
```

Does anybody know any way to solve this other than manually editing JPAControllers.

Below code snippet shows how I tried to store parent.

```
Parent parentObj = new Parent();
parentObj.setDesc("parent");
Collection<Child> childCollection = new ArrayList<>();
Child childObj = new Child();
childObj.setDesc("child1");
childCollection.add(childObj);
Child childObj2 = new Child();
childCollection.add("childObj2");
parentObj.setChildCollection(childCollection);
parentJpaController.create(parentObj);
```

script for creating tables given below

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PARENT`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PARENT` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `DESC` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`CHILD`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`CHILD` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `DESC` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `PARENT` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `FK_CHILD_PARENT` (`PARENT` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CHILD_PARENT`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PARENT` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`PARENT` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: I guess that the @GeneratedValue annotation is missing on the ID properties of the entities, but that is no more than that: a guess. I don't like wizards for the reasons you prove in this question: you still don't know how it technically works and there is no guarantee that what is generated is actually correct. You probably missed a checkbox somewhere.

Comment: Your code is relying on cascade persist to persist the children, while the code provided is assuming these are existing detached children.  Create the children the same way you are the parent before associating them and it should work

Comment: @Gimby `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` is present on the ID properties of the entities. @Chris `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
 private Collection<Child> childCollection;` is there in the Parent entity.